# How do we Model the intermediate era between radiation and matter domination?

Tags: cosmology

It is known that for complete radiation domination the scale factor evolves as -
\begin{equation}
a(t) \propto \sqrt{t}
\end{equation}
Whereas, for the complete matter domination era the scale factor must go as -
\begin{equation}
a(t) \propto t^{2/3}
\end{equation}
How do we model the interface between these two eras? It should depend on many factors such as the time it takes to dilute, the change in relative abundances caused not just by the dilution due to expansion but also by the reactions and non-equilibrium condition post-recombination.

Comment: Note that the answer is quite simple if the matter and radiation are different species. Then it's just a matter of writing down the first Friedmann equation with the two species each scaling appropriately with $a$ and then integrating $\mathrm{d}t=\mathrm{da}/(aH)$. That's the case for our own radiation-to-matter transition at around 52000 years. The calculation is more complicated if you're considering a single dominant species that's becoming nonrelativistic; then you have to account for what the momentum distribution is.

Comment: @Sten Thanks. I was wondering whether the reactions of matter with relativistic species have a considerable effect on their relative abundances, which themselves are subject to temperature and densities which are drastically changing around the recombination era. I thought there might be some deviation of experimentally observed redshift of matter-radiation equality and that predicted by naive scale factor dilution.

Comment: I added a discussion of the magnitude of potential deviations in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the time $t$ is related to the scale factor $a$ through
$$t=\int\mathrm{d}t=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{\dot{a}}=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{a H},\tag{1}$$
where the Hubble rate $H$ is a function of $a$. Meanwhile, for a flat cosmology, $H$ is determined by the first Friedmann equation as
$$H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho,\tag{2}$$
where $\rho$ (also a function of $a$) is the total energy density. So in principle, the only problem is to determine $\rho$ as a function of $a$.

#### If there are independent matter and radiation components,

then we can say that
$$\rho=\rho_{m,0}a^{-3}+\rho_{r,0}a^{-4},\tag{3}$$
where $\rho_{m,0}$ and $\rho_{r,0}$ are the matter and radiation density, respectively, at $a=1$. This is the case for our own universe's transition from radiation to matter domination at a time of about 52000 years. The integral in equation (1) can even be carried out analytically in this case.

In practice, the radiation and matter in our universe are not independent. On the contrary, the radiation and the baryonic component of the matter were strongly kinetically coupled during the transition from radiation to matter domination. How much does this matter?

Matter cools faster than radiation due to the expansion of the universe. For matter, $T\propto a^{-2}$, while for radiation, $T\propto a^{-1}$. Thus, kinetic coupling that maintains matter and radiation at the same temperature would imply a net energy transfer from the radiation to the matter. The radiation would cool slightly faster than $T\propto a^{-1}$, and so its energy density would drop slightly faster than $\rho\propto a^{-4}$. However, there are about a billion photons for every baryon in our universe, so this effect would contribute at the level of one part in a billion.

You could also ask how the matter's nonzero temperature affects its energy density. The temperature at matter-radiation equality was about $10^4~\mathrm{K}\sim 1~\mathrm{eV}$. The mass of a baryon is about $1~\mathrm{GeV}$. So the temperature would contribute here also at the level of one part in a billion.

#### If instead there is a single dominant species that transitions from ultrarelativistic (radiation) to nonrelativistic (matter),

then
$$\rho=\langle E\rangle n,\tag{4}$$
where $n$ is the particle number density, which dilutes as $n\propto a^{-3}$, and
$$\langle E\rangle = \int\sqrt{p^2+m^2}f(\vec p)\mathrm{d}^3\vec p\tag{5}$$
is the average energy per particle. Here $m$ is the particle mass and $f(\vec p)$ is the momentum distribution, which is a function of $a$, because all (peculiar) momenta redshift as $p\propto 1/a$.